# How do I run a Powershell7 Script upon creation of a Windows VM Resource with Terraform (Azure)

Tags: azure, terraform, virtual-machine, powershell-7.0

I have an azure windows VM and I want to be able to run a powershell 7 script (powershell 7+ 100% required) upon creation.  The problem is that none of the vm's come with powershell 7.  Do I have any options?  This needs to be fully automated through terraform.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "your-extension" {
  name                 = "${azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm[0].name}-extension-name"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm[0].id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"

  protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
  {
   "commandToExecute": "powershell7 DO-SOMETHING"
  }
  SETTINGS

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm
  ]
}
```

Comment: Well, how do you plan on running it if you say it's not supported? :)

Comment: Might be the SKU for the VM you are using is the old one so that might be resn powershell 7 version is not suppoted there

Comment: I'm just trying to see if there's a workaround anyone has used @MarkoE

Comment: Another solution for this is to download and install PS7 as part of DSC for your VM you can use automation account and azurerm_virtual_machine_extension, publisher = "Microsoft.Powershell",  type = "DSC"

Answer (score -1):

This might be possiblities you are using an old SKU or image would suggest you upgrade your SKU to  `sku  = "2019-Datacenter"` or `sku  = "2016-Datacenter"`

```
 source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
```

---

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "example" {
  name                 = "hostname2"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.4"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -Command \"${local.powershell_command}\""
    }
SETTINGS
  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.example
  ]
}
```

You can check my this [***thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72007709/how-to-create-azurerm-virtual-machine-extension-with-a-network-watcher-installed) which i have answered long back regarding how to install a extenion on Azure Virtual Machine

Comment: The problem is that this still installs powrrshell 5.1 by default and even the windows 11 images or 2022 data center only have that. Not sure if anyone knows of a workaround.

Comment: @rahulKumarShaw powershell.exe is Powershell 5.1. The executable for Powershell 7 is pwsh.exe. But as others have mentioned none of the SKUs come with Powershell 7, it would have to be downloaded and installed separately